# What is the difference between functional component and class component to define inside function's property type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, eslint

What is the difference between functional component and class component to define function's property type inside?

For example,

In class component, there is no problems.

```js
class ListView extends React.Component {
...
  renderItem: SectionListRenderItem<Circle> = ({ item }) => { // no lint warning
    const { circleStore } = this.props
    return (
      <CircleList
        hideButton
        title={item.title}
        desc={item.desc}
        iconSource={{ uri: item.logoImageUrl }}
        onPress={() => circleStore && circleStore.setCurrentCircle(item)}
      ></CircleList>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SectionListView ... />
    )
  }
}
...
```

In functional component, it makes `'item' is missing in props validation - eslint(react/prop-types)` ploblem as below.

```js
...
const ListView = (props: Props) => {
  const renderItem: SectionListRenderItem<Circle> = ({ item }) => (  // lint warning
    <CircleList
      hideButton
      title={item.title}
      desc={item.desc}
      iconSource={{ uri: item.logoImageUrl }}
      onPress={() => {}}
    ></CircleList>
  )

  ...

  return (
    <SectionListView ... />
  )
}
...
```

It can be fixed as below code

```js
  const renderItem: SectionListRenderItem<Circle> = ({ item }) => (
```

change to

```js
  const renderItem: SectionListRenderItem<Circle> = ({ item }: { item: Circle }) => (
```

`Circle` is the interface I declared.

I wonder why this happens and what difference there is. 
Only `renderItem` in stateless component makes a lint error in comparison to a class component.

### Full source

```js
interface Props {
  popularCircles: Circle[]
  recentCircles: Circle[]
  onPressSection?: (section: Circle) => void
  onPressCircle?: (circle: Circle) => void
}

export const Main = ({
  popularCircles,
  recentCircles,
  onPressCircle,
}: Props) => {
  const renderSectionHeader = ({ section: { title } }: SectionHeader) => {
    return (
      <SectionHeaderCell
        title={title}
        buttonTitle={''}
        disabled
      ></SectionHeaderCell>
    )
  }

  const renderItem: SectionListRenderItem<Circle> = ({ 
    item,
  }) => ( // This line makes a eslint warning only in functional component.
    <CircleList
      hideButton
      title={item.title}
      desc={item.desc}
      iconSource={{ uri: item.logoImageUrl }}
      onPress={() => onPressCircle && onPressCircle(item)}
    ></CircleList>
  )

  return (
    <Container>
      <SectionList
        sections={[
          {
            title: 'Title1',
            data: popularCircles,
          },
          {
            title: 'Title2',
            data: recentCircles,
          },
        ]}
        renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Main
```

Circle.d.ts

```js
export interface Circle {
  circleId: number
  title: string
  desc: string
  logoImageUrl?: string
}
```

Comment: Can you show us, where you declare these functions within your files?

Comment: @Domino987 I added more information.

Comment: if SectionListRenderItem is: interface SectionListRenderItem<T>: ({item: T}) => void; it should not make a difference. Are you sure that you import it correctly?

Comment: @Domino987 I checked a lot. It is sure. That is why I ask this question.

Comment: Can you show your interfaces SectionRenderItem and Circle?

Comment: @Domino987 I added full source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197453/discussion-between-domino987-and-jeff-gu-kang).

Comment: I think it is a kind of bug in ESLint.